# Angular Validation is not working when I click on the field and and without typing anything I tab out from that field

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I am working on validations in my form through angular JS. My validations are working when I am typing something in boxes and removing the value. My issue is that I also want to show validations in my page when after refreshing the page, I am only clicking on any field and tabing out of that field. 
Below is one of the validation field of my form-

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.number.$invalid && !myForm.number.$pristine }">

    <label for="Number" style="color:#767676" class="" ng-hide="myForm.number.$invalid && !myForm.number.$pristine ">Number</label>
                       <label class="error_message_text" ng-show="myForm.number.$invalid &&  !myForm.number.$pristine">
                            Please enter the number
                        </label><br>
    <input type="number" name="number" class="form-control" ng-model="user.planNo" required>

</div>
```

I have created a plunker here-
https://plnkr.co/edit/Zu43LfNZ2K25OL5aCV9g?p=preview.

Can anyone help me how I will get that validation in my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `$touched` property

```
<label for="UserName" style="color:#767676" class="" ng-hide="myForm.name.$error.required && myForm.name.$touched">Name</label>
<label class="error_message_text" ng-show="myForm.name.$error.required && myForm.name.$touched">Please enter the name</label><br>
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.number" required/>
```

Here's a working `plunker` - https://plnkr.co/edit/6eyglRiY15QrcKBUaSpX?p=preview  - check name input

Comment: This is fine but I want border color also should changed to red along with error message @irhabi

Comment: Add has-error class on $invalid and $touched:
https://plnkr.co/edit/6eyglRiY15QrcKBUaSpX?p=preview